# What went wrong in the practise of Hinduism?

Tags: ethics, society, eastern-philosophy

**Remarks on the Caste System**

The caste system was first mentioned in Manu Smriti (and not Vedas). The ultimate objective was to construct an ideal society in which everyone
is happy. The caste of a person was meant to be decided based on a persons
inherent demonstrated qualities, and not based on a persons birth — I assume that each person was meant to decide their own caste.

This would suggest that the modern form of the caste system is wrong, because it has become a sytem based on ones birth. This is politically significant, as this form of caste is considered as one of the biggest draw backs of Hinduism by others. Outside of Buddhism and Sikhism, nothing much has been
done to follow the correct practice of the caste system.

**Remarks on Scripture**

Is it not possible that there is a scripture prior to Vedas? A scripture that explained only the core principles? At present we find people with power get their things done. But the honest and truthful people do not get their things done (except enlightenment, which can be pursued independently). Is it not possible that Vedas (and also Manusmriti) were manipulated for selfish motives?

Mahavakyas (Tat Tvam Asi) in Vedas are the core of Humanity. Then why are we giving higher importance other parts of the Veda (like caste system)? There are many points in Vedas, Manusmrithi, *etc*. which restricts a human being's freedom (such as freedom to choose the work); whereas Hinduism is meant to promote freedom. So are not these scriptures wrong?

**Remarks on Practice of Hinduism**

Hinduism has always been perfect. Then how come it is not perfect now? Compared to any other country, India has been following Vedas better. Then, why is it that U.S., Germany, *etc.* are evidently superior to India in terms of scientific knowledge, wealth and general ethics?

Unless we start practicing the right way of Hinduism, won't the world risk losing Hinduism? Other religions might try to eliminate / convert Hindus. Some will convert out of free will — Hinduism has declined by around 3% since 1961, and Islam has grown by 3% in India [[reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_India)]. Ultimately, is
there not a risk that future human being might not even get a chance to
understand Hinduism?

"Sati" was never a practice mentioned in any of Hindu scriptures, including Vedas and Manu Smriti. Neither did Shiva/Sati tell anybody to do this. It was followed in India by "people". The religion had nothing to do with this practice.

As to the status of women: their proper status is same as men. There are
references to certain restrictions on women, but these restrictions might have
been manipulations made by people. In Hinduism, everyone is equal.

We could have done much better. When, one by one, people came and tried to destroy Hinduism (including human beings and resources — Nalanda etc.), we Hindus (including Brahmins, Kshtariya, Vasihyas and Shudras) did not do enough to protect people. Our actions were not right. (We did not act as much as we should have.)

Our discrimination was wrong. We did not know whether a visitor (Mughals, Britishers) came for our good/bad. We applied "Athithi devoh
bhava" and forgot what Krishna says in Bhagavad gita about selfless action. At present, most (95%) of Hindus (including Brahmins, Kshtariya, Vasihyas and Shudras) are selfish and do not follow their conscience.

Comment: After reading through your question, I'm not exactly sure what your asking, unless you want a general critique of what you've written. In that case, the line that stood out to me was: "Hinduism has always been perfect.  Then how come we are not perfect now?" You're going to have a hard time proving that *anything* has *ever* been perfect. Hard as in historically impossible.

Comment: This question is quite specific to the history – and from the sounds of it, the original motivations – of Hinduism as a religion and a basis of culture, which doesn't seem to be on topic to me. (Questions of a similar vein regarding Christianity or Islam would probably be quickly be forwarded to [Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/) or [Islam.SE](http://islam.stackexchange.com/) respectively.)

Comment: Most of these points aren't really about philosophy; but those that are could be handled as individual queries. Note that great questions ask about some *specific* problem you are encountering.

Comment: This appears to be a series of questions and speculations about Indian history.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap : Agreed.  I expected a Hinduism.SE, but was not there.  Hence posted here.

Comment: @All : Appreciate that most of the down votes are accompanies by comments to inform why you have down voted,

Comment: I have revised the post to present the remarks, arguments, and questions in a more fluid style which would be more appropriate, while attempting to preserve the meaning.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap  Thank you.  I do understand the effort and time you have taken.

Comment: Caste appears to be an Indian particularisation of a general phenomena - social differentiation - this is not peculiar to India, for example in Europe there was the feudal system, the lowest strata of which were Serfs - it would be interesting to compare them with the Dalits of India. My understanding is that the Vedas were an Oral tradition for many centuries before they were written down. There could be no scripture before the Vedas when we understand scripture as in *written down*.

Comment: Apparently we are now in the era of the Kala Yug, the age of vice - so even perfect things are tainted and corrupted, such as Hinduism.  Gayatri Spivak (a postcolonial theorist) wrote an essay *Can the subaltern speaks* which critically addresses the concerns you raise about *sati*, whereas William Dalrymple in *the age of Kali* writes about it from the perspective of modern media-mediated secular India and traditional rural India. He also notes that there have been only 40 satis recorded since Independence, hardly a large number when one thinks of the immense population of India.

Comment: and that there are Greek myths that record its presence in Europe, interestingly I'd note a literary parallel in *Romeo & Juliet*. Gayatri also says that India is a European invention, and by extension so is Hinduism. There are instead many local expressions of identity - both religous and cultural.

Comment: I've placed my answer in the comments as the question is now closed, which is most likely due to presentation rather than lack of content. I'd also note that the tone of the question may reveal the *epistemic violence* that Gayatri mentions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) You are correct. Manu said caste is based on a person's own tendencies. Caste is a social custom, not a religious custom (Swami Vivekananda) Most parts of India follow local customs, not the laws of Manu (for example: brahmins in the south do not do animal sacrifice, Bengali brahmins do)

2) The Vedas are the eternal truths of God, not the written documents. The written truths of what you think of as the Vedas are the truths revealed to the Rishis. Do not get the written documents confused with the eternal truths. Veda has existed forever and will exist forever. Yes, Hinduism believes in complete freedom - freedom from the senses, not freedom of the senses. There is no complete freedom in the senses, the only thing completely free is the Atman, beyond the sensual world.

3) The west is the master of manipulating the outside material world. Hinduism is the master of manipulating the inner world....
Most of what I have read about Hinduism in Wikipedia is downright wrong....women are given a high status in the Upanishads......

4) read The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda - online edition at https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/master_index.htm

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda: Yes Swamiji. Well said. Women are not only given high status in *Upanishads*, but in the *Puranas* as well. And no one should believe Wikipedia, since anyone can create an account and write whatever he/she wants.

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7144/does-japa-wipes-good-karma-also  ... swamiji please help me

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda I consider statements like *The Vedas are the eternal truths of God*  or *Veda has existed forever and will exist forever* - uttered without giving any argument - a bit problematic in the context of this philosophical blog. Because you cannot presuppose that views like these are common sense for all participants. I hold that the minimal requirement of any philosophiocal method is to give arguments to convince your dialog partners. What do you think?

Comment: Anything that is ever written, it is and was written by Human. There is not eternal truth - but a phenomenon is explained in human language in a way that provides a better explanation of the observation and/or process. That is why we revise our hypothesis and answers to it, thereby make it better suited and explanatory. Women are treated with respect in many other civilizations too, but the problem is - it happen only when the civilization is prospering. When civilization reaches it height either it collapses on it own weight or is conquered there by inflicting disease on it.

Comment: @JoWehler - He did not say what the eternal truths are, just that there are eternal truths referred to by the word 'Vedas'. This seems fair enough. He is explaining something about the Vedas, and doing great, not trying to persuade you to adopt a philosophical position.  .

Comment: @Swami Your answer is nonsense. (1) Manusmriti is the worst book in the world if one looks from the Human rights prespective. Caste cannot be changed( ie son of a Shudra will always remain a Shudra)- Source of both these facts: Philosophy of Hinduism by B. R. Ambedkar.

Comment: @JoWehler Have a look at my comment too.

Comment: @Swami (2)"The Vedas are the eternal truths of God, not the written documents. Vedas have existed forever and will exist forever." There is absolutely no proof of these statement.

Comment: @Swami "Yes, Hinduism believes in complete freedom" Then why is there caste system in Hinduism? Why are Sudras and Ati-sudras not allowed to get education , own weapon , own land.

Comment: @Swami  (3)"Hinduism is the master of manipulating the inner world." How exactly? Any proof of this? Why should I believe you? What exactly is "inner" and "outer world"?

Comment: @Swami (4) If one reads Chapter 4 of the book Debrahmanising History by Braj Ranjan Mani , one can easily see that Vivekananda was a very casteist and racist person. So, why are you promoting his book here?

Comment: @JoWehler If you are interested in more discussion have a look at my comments.